# jquery animate and hide element under another element

Tags: jquery

I have problem with the following scenario.

I have 2 divs (it's an example, see the picture) When I click on the yellow div, it's being animated and moved to the left to be completely hidden under the red div.

I know I must use `$.animate()` function to make the yellow div movement, but how to hide it under the red div ?

[image]

Comment: It's all about position in the document and the order of elements, or you could just cheat and use z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` is what you need, however you need to ensure that your elements are set correctly with regard to the `position` of parents. Try this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="centre"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#left {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
#right {
    z-index: 10;
}
#centre {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 15;
}
```

Note, I've reduced the CSS here to the important attributes. The full version is in the fiddle.

```
$('#centre').click(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.animate({ left: "-=" + $el.width() });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/j49w5/1/)